# Skipping modifying CTE and returning an existing key instead of inserting a new one (if value already exists)

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I am writing a query in PostgreSQL that I use in my php code where a user is supposed to be able to add actors to the list of actors by typing the actors name. I'm using a modifying CTE to do this because it needs to update three tables in the database:

- Person(Person_ID:Serial, Name: Varchar,... other not relevant information, it's ok to leave null)
- Personnel(Personnel_ID:Serial, Role: Varchar, Person_ID:Int (FK))
  FilmPeople(Personnel_ID (FK), Media_ID (FK))
- So the actor as a person is in the person table, then connected to a role in personnel, and the role is then connected to a media_ID.

The query so far:

```
WITH person_cte AS (
     INSERT INTO Person(Name)
     SELECT :actorname
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM person WHERE name = :actorname2)
     RETURNING person_id
     ),
     personnel_cte AS (
     INSERT INTO Personnel(role, person_id)
     SELECT 'Actor', person_id FROM person_cte
     RETURNING personnel_id
     )
     INSERT INTO FilmPeople(Personnel_ID, Media_ID)
     SELECT personnel_id, :id from personnel_cte¨
```

So the problem as you guys probably see is that my query so far only works if the actor doesnt exist in the database at all. It fails if it finds the actor in the Person table. What I actually want is if the Actor exists in person, then don't insert anything but do return the already existing person_id to the next cte. And then the same thing there, if the personnel (role) already exists for this actor, then move on with the personnel_id and only add the actor to the last table to connect him/her to a movie. And then even here, if it already exists then don't do anything.

EDIT: This is how the tables are created as of now:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
Person_ID serial,
Name varchar(255),
DateOfBirth date,
Gender varchar(45),
CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY (Person_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Personnel(
Personnel_ID serial,
Role varchar(255),
Person_ID bigint,
CONSTRAINT PK_Personnel PRIMARY KEY (Personnel_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_PersonPersonnel FOREIGN KEY (Person_ID)
REFERENCES Person(Person_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE FilmPeople(
Personnel_ID bigint,
Media_ID int,
CONSTRAINT PK_FilmPeople PRIMARY KEY (Personnel_ID, Media_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_PersonnelFilmPeople FOREIGN KEY (Personnel_ID)
REFERENCES Personnel(Personnel_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_MediaFilmPeople FOREIGN KEY (Media_ID)
REFERENCES Media(Media_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When nothing is inserted, the `returning` clause comes back empty - so this is not the approach you want here. Instead, I would recommed joining the tables. For this to work properly, I would strongly suggest having unique keys on each table, like so:

```
person(name)
personnel(role,person_id)
filmpeople(personnel_id, media_id)
```

Then you can use `on conflict`:

```
with 
    person_cte as (
        insert into person(name)
        values (:actorname)
        on conflict (name) do nothing
    ),
    personnel_cte as (
        insert into personnel(role, person_id)
        select 'actor', p.person_id 
        from person p
        where p.name = :actorname
        on conflict (role, person_id) do nothing
     )
insert into filmpeople(personnel_id, media_id)
select personnel_id, :id 
from pl.personnel pl
inner person p on p.person_id = pl.person_id
where p.name = :actorname and pl.role = 'actor'
on conflict (personnel_id, media_id) do nothing
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a little confused about the first paragraph about the unique keys, your example is exactly how the tables are or am I missing something? Person has Person_ID, Personnel has Personnel_ID and then filmpeople combines personnel with media key.

Comment: @SanjinRedzepagic: I mean you should have unique constraints as described in the first paragraph (that might be the case already). For example, in table `filmpeople`, this tuple of columns should be defined as `unique`: `(personnel_id, media_id)`

Comment: I'm sorry for being a little daft, I've added how the tables are created as of now in the original post. Could you look at that and tell me what changes you mean need to be made?

Comment: What @GMB suggests is that you add a unique business key to each table, then use this key in each successive cte or the main query, For the Person table you need "Alter table add constraint person_bk unique name;"  Similar alter table statement apply to the other tables.